# Keep clean SimpleIoc initialization when reusing UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, mvvm

Originally I had `ChildUserControl` inside `ParentUserControl` inside `MainWindow` with this view-models (here only constructors):

```
public MainViewModel(IParentViewModel pvm) {}

public ParentViewModel(IChildViewModel cvm) {}

public ChildViewModel(IMessenger m) {}
```

And straightforward DI initialization in `ViewModelLocator`:

```
var container = SimpleIoc.Default;
container.Register<IMessenger, Messenger>();
container.Register<IParentViewModel, ParentViewModel>();
container.Register<IChildViewModel, ChildViewModel>();
container.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
...
public IMainViewModel MainViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMainViewModel>();
```

Then I needed to add second `ParentUserControl` instance near the first one, and let them work independently. `MainViewModel` constructor became to look like this:

```
public MainViewModel(IParentViewModel pvm1, IParentViewModel pvm2) {}
```

But DI initialization changed dramatically:

```
container.Register<IMessenger, Messenger>();

container.Register<IParentViewModel>(
    () => new ParentViewModel(new ChildViewModel(container.GetInstance<IMessenger>("key1"))),
    "key1");

container.Register<IParentViewModel>(
    () => new ParentViewModel(new ChildViewModel(container.GetInstance<IMessenger>("key2"))),
    "key2");

container.Register<IMainViewModel>(() => new MainViewModel(
    container.GetInstance<IParentViewModel>("key1"),
    container.GetInstance<IParentViewModel>("key2")));
```

As you can see, now I have to point to concrete `ParentViewModel` and `ChildViewModel` classes in several places, and I also have to manually use `GetInstance` everywhere. I think this is not good.

What can you tell about this latter DI initialization? I guess it can't be improved by *SimpleIoc*, but can *Unity* or *Ninject* help in this situation?

Comment: This is not DI but service locator. They work differently.

Comment: My view models receive interfaces for concrete entities, this is why I name it DI. In case of service locator, they would have to receive service locator instances, like `public MainViewModel(ViewModelServiceLocator locator)`, wouldn't they? @t3chb0t